# AJAX error when deleting CSS part?

Tags: php, css, ajax

EDIT: It's OK. The problem was a constant variable missing, and missing argument for one function....

I have a AJAX function which call a page in PHP/

My php page is like this :

```
   if ($this->display->displayHeader == 1) {
        print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DISPLAY_HEADER\">";
        require("includes/header.php");
        print "</div>";
    }
    if ($this->display->displayTitle == 1) {
        print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DISPLAY_TITLE\">";
        require($this->display->dir."display_titre.php");
        print "</div>";
    }
    if ($this->display->displayNavigation == 1) {
        print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DISPLAY_NAVIGATION\">";
        require($this->display->dir."display_navigation.php");
        print "</div>";
    }
    print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DISPLAY_CONTENT\">";
    require($this->display->dir.$this->page);
    print "</div>";

    print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DOCUMENT_TITLE\">";
    print WEBSITE_NAME_TITLE . " - " . $this->display->documentTitle;
    print "</div>";

    if ($this->display->displayFooter == 1) {
        print "<div id=\"AJXCALL_DISPLAY_FOOTER\">";
        require('includes/footer.php');
        print "</div>";
    }
```

All page included by php contains CSS, JS and HTML.

AJAX request retrieve this data, filter and split them to re-construct my web page.
All work but, if I delete some part of CSS style in header.php, ajax request gone wrong... how that can be possible ?! I never saw that before...

AJAX code (simplified) :

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: post,
  async: true,
  success: function(data){ 

        WEBSITE.console('1','* Data received, filter and splitting...');

          hostname = $(data).filter('#AJX_PARAMS_HOSTNAME');
[....]
},
error: function(e) {
  console.log('LOWYD LOAD ERROR : FORCE LOAD');

  console.log(e);
},
```

All work but if I delete some part of CSS code in header.php or content, AJAX request gone wrong... it's crazy...

Comment: Please add your ajax code as well

Comment: Trying to figure out your issue, as on changing css I don't think that it would effect Ajax at all. Until on the ajax page same css is being called